# VirtualBox and Google Compute Engine

Tags: virtualbox, google-compute-engine

Can I run VirtualBox and an active VM on a server hosted on Google Compute Engine? If yes, what are the steps? Just install it and build the VM through VNC?

So far I have found similar solution for DigitalOcean where you simply install VirtualBox, xfce, VNC, etc. and it runs.

Comment: I should also add that running a VM on Virtualbox on a VM isn't strictly necessary: you're paying additional overhead that you don't need. A VM on Google Compute Engine is something you can connect to directly over VNC: just create a VM, ssh into it, install your packages, then connect by VNC, and you're done. I'm curious why you want to run a VM manager in a VM.

Comment: Excellent answers but how on earth does this actually work? GCE instances are already virtualised! *Queue inception music*

Comment: @DanielJames – this is called "nested virtualization"; it's not exactly black magic, but depending on the implementation, it may get slower, you may not get hardware acceleration, etc. as you go deeper. I'm still unclear what the use case is behind this question, but haven't heard back from the OP.

Comment: I teach a class on Operating systems. I have a use case, I am trying to host Jenkins on GCE. This Jenkins instance should be able to spin up vagrant VMs in order to properly test student submissions. So far everything seems to work, but I haven't been able to ssh into the vagrant instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the same approach will work on a GCE VM.

You can also use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with the [Google Compute Engine plugin](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-google) to automate creation of virtual machines and GCE VMs.

Answer (score 12):

1. Create GCE instance
2. SSH to that instance
3. Download and install Virtualbox (wget [DEB](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.2/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb) + sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5*.deb)
4. Upgrade system, build and install kernel modules

   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get upgrade`
   - `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
   - `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`
   - `sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
   - `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`
5. Profit!

*To check if all is good just run `VBoxManage --version`. If some other errors are present google and resolve*

Comment: I tried this and got an error "VT-x is not available".  Fixed by following instructions at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances

Comment: have you tried? can you run windows inside this virtual box?